# webservice client session management

Tags: java, spring, web-services, session, jax-ws

So I am building this Webservice client and the Webservice (server) requires that I maintain a session and use a unique key, (not the JSESSIONID) generated by the client, only for that session. So I did the obvious.

```
((BindingProvider)service).getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.SESSION_MAINTAIN_PROPERTY, true);
```

Now this works great and I store the unique key and JSESSIONID is part of the headers etc.

The problem I have is that when I want to create a new session. So, another user logs in, I create a new unique key, authorize the user and get a new JSESSIONID. The authorization call seems to still add the other JSESSIONID to the headers and so the Webservice rejects the call. I am not sure how to tell my client service to create a new session? Do I just go `new Service.getPort()` and use that instance (doesn't seem best practice)? Can I create a Spring bean with a prototype scope (didn't seem to work but maybe I have scoped the wrong bean)? I even tried removing the JSESSIONID from the headers but it never seems to exist when I handle the message. If you need any thing (logs/traces/code) just shout and I'll edit the post.

Comment: Why do you say `getPort()` isn't best practice? Creating a new instance seems perfectly acceptable for using a new server-side session; reusing a port instance seems the right path for multiple service calls sharing the same session. This tutorial tends to agree: https://weblogs.java.net/blog/ramapulavarthi/archive/2006/06/maintaining_ses.html

Comment: Seems the server side still doesn't like me doing this. It is very specific about matching JSessionid's with client generated Id's and it just seems to allow only one session. Stupid thing. Thanks for your help though.